# Convert 17-digit precision unix time (UTC) to date fromat In javascript

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I got time token like this from `14512768065185892` from PubNub.I need to convert this time token into following format `dd/mm/yy`.

Any one please provide one method to convert time stamp to date format.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [*Date* constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value) can be passed a time value that is milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). The value you have seems to have 4 digits too many, so just divide by 1e4 (or whatever value is appropriate):

```js
var timeValue = 14512768065185892;
document.write(new Date(timeValue/1e4));
```

There are plenty of questions and answers here on how to format the output as dd/mm/yy (which is a very ambiguous format), e.g.

```js
function formatDMYY(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '/' + z(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + z(d.getFullYear()%1e3);
}

document.write(formatDMYY(new Date(14512768065185892/1e4)));
```

Comment: Thank You for this great Answer!!

Comment: @RobG Can you please help me?

I am trying to convert timestamp 2016-02-11 03:31:18 to pubnub timestamp of 17-digit precision unix time (UTC) something like 13406746780720711 given in reference url given by pubnub
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#history_example_2

Comment: @ShashankShah—parse the string to create a Date object (e.g. my answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169209/javascript-date-parse-return-nan-in-mozilla-browser/35169689#35169689)), then use *getTime*. Note that the precision is integer milliseconds, which might be 0 (for 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Comment: @RobG  I have tried following code but still 10 digit value not 17-Digit precision timestamp

function parseDateTime(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5])
}


date = new Date(parseDateTime("2011-01-26 13:51:50") / 1000);
console.log(date.getTime()); // Gives 1296030110
</script>

Answer (score 1):

PubNub times have an extra 7 digits of precision above standard UNIX time stamps (seconds) so the first step is to divide it by 10<sup>7</sup>. That gives you `1451276806` which, when you test it in a [converter](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), you get `12/28/2015 @ 4:26am (UTC)` (using the frankly bizarre<sup>(1)</sup> US date format) so it seems to be reasonable.

In terms of using Javascript to do this, you can pass the number of milliseconds to `Date` to have an object instantiated for you:

```
var dtobj = new Date(1451276806518);
```

keeping in mind that the *millisecond* value entails you dividing by 10<sup>4</sup> (lopping off the final four digits) rather than 10<sup>7</sup>.

Once you have the date object, you can use standard methods to get it in the format you want, such as:

```
var dtobj = new Date(1451276806518);
var dtdd = ('0' + (dtobj.getDate())).slice(-2);
var dtmm = ('0' + (dtobj.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var dtyy = ('0' + (getFullYear() % 100)).slice(-2);

document.write(dtdd + "/" + dtmm + "/" + dtyy);
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I swear some committee must have taken the worst bits from all date formats to indicate what needed to be discarded, then some *other* committee accidentally took that as a recommendation. Needless to say, I'm a big fan of ISO 8601 :-)

Comment: The EMCAScript [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is entirely implementation dependent, so your "committee" is a bunch of developers taking a guess at what users might want. Even TC39 [*can't agree to fully adopt ISO 8601*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87), rather sad.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the last 4 characters, and use this timestamp in `Date` constructor:

```
new Date(+str.substr(0, str.length - 4))
```

However, JS doesn't support "dd/mm/yyyy" format, and you will have to implement it yourself or use third-party libraries like Moment.js.

Here is the working demo:

```js
Date.parsePubNub = function(str) {
    return new Date(+str.substr(0, str.length - 4));
};

Date.prototype.toDDMMYYYY = function()
{
  return ("0" + this.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + this.getFullYear();
};

var str = "14512768065185892";
document.body.innerText = Date.parsePubNub(str).toDDMMYYYY();
```