# convert timestamp to pubnub timestamp of 17-digit precision unix time (UTC)

Tags: pubnub

I am trying to convert timestamp 2016-02-11 03:31:18 to pubnub timestamp of 17-digit precision unix time (UTC) something like 13406746780720711 given in reference url given by [pubnub](http://pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#history_example) 
I have tried following but no luck

```
function parseDateTime(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5])
}
date = new Date(parseDateTime("2015-02-11 02:10:54") / 10000);
console.log(date.getTime());//142360085
```

Above example gives output `142360085` which is 10 characters where pubnub asks for 17 digit timestamp.

Reason behind doing this is i want to fetch unread messages of particular user and send an email at EOD via email.

After converting mytimestamp to 17-digit precision unix time (UTC) i will pass it to [pubnub history function](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history#retrieving_from_a_time_interval)  and get unread messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 17-digit precision unix time (UTC) to date fromat In javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487986/convert-17-digit-precision-unix-time-utc-to-date-fromat-in-javascript)

Comment: In Android https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126795/5788247

Answer (score 5):

## Convert Unix Timestamp to PubNub Timetoken 17-digit Precision

Easy as pie: **`timestamp * 10000`**

Except for PHP.  ❌ **PHP** ❌ does not support this level of integer precision! You can instead use String Concatenation and Coercion.

```
$tt = $unixtime_milliseconds . "0000";
```

> Your unix time must be represented in millisecond precision, **no fractions / no floats**.

Try out this example using JavaScript.

```js
// Vars
var timestamp   = +new Date;
var unix_time   = document.getElementById("unix-timestamp");
var pubnub_time = document.getElementById("pubnub-timetoken");

// Conversion
function unix_to_pubnub(time) {
    return time * 10000;
}

// Update Time
unix_time.innerHTML   = timestamp;
pubnub_time.innerHTML = unix_to_pubnub(timestamp);
```

```html
<span id="unix-timestamp"></span> - Unix Timestamp <br>
<span id="pubnub-timetoken"></span> - PubNub Timetoken
```

Comment: function parseDateTime(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5])
}
var timestamp   = parseDateTime("2015-02-11 02:10:54");
var unix_time   = document.getElementById("unix-timestamp");
var pubnub_time = document.getElementById("pubnub-timetoken");
// Conversion
function unix_to_pubnub(time) {
    return time * 10000;
}
// Update Time
unix_time.innerHTML   = timestamp;
pubnub_time.innerHTML = unix_to_pubnub(timestamp);

@PubNub can you please check the code?i mean this is correct what i am doing ?i am passing date not date object here. 
correct me if wrong.

Comment: On above comment i am trying to convert date (string) to pubnub timetoken which produce 14236008540000000 - PubNub Timetoken i hope this is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It will not match a message that is in your history for that channel but it will return results before or after that timetoken depending on which parameter you use (start or end).

Comment: Nope! It's not working for me! :( even i tried using php sdk as well but no luck please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451863/get-unread-messages-on-particular-channel-pubnub-php-sdk hope you'll help.

Comment: ❌ **PHP** ❌ does not support this level of integer precision!  you may instead want to use String Concatenation and Coercion.  **`$tt = $unixtime_milliseconds . "0000";`**  You unix time must be millisecond precision.

Comment: This answer unfortunately conflicts with the PubNub history API calls in the sense that you no longer exclude (start) or include (end) a history entry if using a "last read" timetoken that artificially ends in '0000.'

Comment: Good point.  If your VM doesn't support the required precision then you will need to round to the closest decimal or use string format.

Answer (score 3):

**In Android get Current TimeToken**

```
  static Long getCurrentHourToken() {
        return (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) * 10000L;
    }

    static Long getBeforeHourToken(int hours) {
        return (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours)) * 10000L;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**In iOS how you can get current timestamp. This is written for PubNub.**

```
 static func currentTimeInMilliSeconds()-> CUnsignedLongLong {
           let currentDate = Date()
           let since1970 = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970
           return CUnsignedLongLong(since1970 * 1000)
       }
```

Comment: That's incorrect. PubNub converts Timetoken to date with `Int64(self / 10_000_000)`. So in another direction, we need to do like this `Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 10_000_000)`.