# Date Handling Unix Date Incorrectly (or I'm using Date incorrectly?)

Tags: javascript, unix

I have the following data structure. The first column is intervals. The first row of the interval datum is a unix time and the subsequent data are intervals (i.e. 300*1, 300*2, ect). The other column is the data values. Here is the head of the data:

```
a1521207300,555.45
1,554.53
2,554.07
3,553.9
4,552.67
```

And here I went about converting the unix time to a `Date` object. The `a` here is ornamental, so I `slice()` at 1 like so:

```
    var rawTime = data[0].interval;
    var timeValue = Math.round(rawTime.slice(1));
    console.log(timeValue)
    console.log(new Date(timeValue))
```

I also tried using `parseInt()` instead of `round()`. The console shows that this unix time is equivalent to: `Jan 18 1970` which I had quite the guffaw at. Then I got to thinking, maybe I did something wrong. It's supposed to be a very recent date -- March 16th 2018. This is strange because my understanding is that javascript can be passed a unix date directly as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487986/convert-17-digit-precision-unix-time-utc-to-date-fromat-in-javascript).

I also checked the unix time at a conversion site: www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Which confirmed that it's indeed a March 16th 2018 timestamp.

**Question:** Why is this unix date for my March 2018 data being treated like a 1970's date? Maybe the `a` is actually doing something after all... Anyway, what is the correct way to handle this time stamp? It's only 10 numerical digits, it does not seem to be a precision problem. `Date` can handle unix times up to 13 digits I believe.

Comment: January 18, 1970 would be a number like 1483200.  Any idea how that number could have crept in?

Comment: @SteveSummit Actually no, I haven't seen a number like that. It's a pretty simple program I have going. I've triple checked things for what it's worth. Maybe my IDE is bugged or something.

Comment: When I take away `new` from `new Date` it seems to be ok. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), when you invoke `new Date(value)` with an integer value, it is used as the number of *milliseconds* since January 1, 1970. To get the date you want, the value 1521207300 appears to be number of seconds instead of milliseconds. That is, you missed a factor of 1000. `new Date(1521207300000)` gives Fri Mar 16 2018.

> When I take away new from new Date it seems to be ok. Not sure why though.

The documentation mentions the different behavior:

> Note: JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.

It seems when called as a function `Date(value)`, it treats the value as the number of seconds, instead of milliseconds. I didn't dig deep enough to confirm this, because it doesn't matter: the documentation says to not use it this way (and since it gives a string instead of a date object, it's not very useful anyway).